# Yii limit on related model while querying

Tags: php, sql, yii, limit

I ran into limit problem. The code that I'm using is the following:

```
$model = PostCategory::model();
  $record = $model->with(array(
    'posts'=>array(
      'order'=>'posts.createTime DESC',
      'limit'=>3,
))->findByPK($id);
```

I want to limit the posts queried for paging purposes. I've also tried to add

```
'together'=>true
```

after limit, this doesn't help too.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: +1 good question, i checked the query that is executed, `limit` never gets appended in the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will definitely work, just tested :

```
$model = PostCategory::model();
$record = $model->with(array(
  'posts'=>array(
     'order'=>'posts.createTime DESC',
  ))->findByPK($id,
             array('limit'=>3,'together'=>true) // adding this works
);
```

Comment: let me know if you need any clarifications, and how it works out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a wiki on [parameterized named scopes](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/441/parameterized-named-scope-re-use-the-same-set-of-filtering-criteria-in-various-models-and-controllers-also-re-use-the-same-parameterized-named-scope-in-all-find-functions-and-in-dataprovider).

But if you want to filter records in RELATED tables while using Relational Query, then you should use defaultScope().

Here is a wiki on [defaultScope](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/486/defaultscope/) and it also shows how to bypass defaultScope when it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could add scope in your Post model and use

## PostModel.php

```
public function recent( $limit = 3 ) {

    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
        'order' => $this->getTableAlias(false, false).'.createTime DESC',
        'limit' => (int) $limit,
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

## MyController.php

```
$record = $model->with('posts:recent')->findByPK($id);
```

And you have clean and readable code.

See more info about scopes
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes

And this forum post how to give params to your scope using *->with*
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/23358-parameterized-vs-named-scopes-question-using-yii-118/